# Unable to select the first swatch in Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento-2.3

I want to select the first swatch. For that I am doing something like this.

```
var gallery = $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]', $('.column.main'));
gallery.on('gallery:loaded', function () {
        $('.swatch-attribute .swatch-attribute-options', context).each(function() {
             $('.swatch-option:not(.disabled)', this).first().click();
        });
    });
```

But it is throwing error. We are using Magento 2.3.6 .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the element `$('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]', $('.column.main'))` does not exist on the page, therefore element is undefined.